# Find the volume of body K

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

An exam type question regarding volume integrals, I know a bit how to solve them but some things are still unclear. especially because of the way this question was written

> Let $K$ be the body in $\mathbb R^3$ be given by
> $$K=  \{(x, y, z)| x \ge y^2, x-y\le 2 , 0 \le z \le x\}.$$
> Find the volume of $K$.

My approach:

What I have tried is to first set-up the three integral signs but that's where it already goes wrong. You can see that you can integrate $z$ from $0$ to $x$ and with some shifting around you can see that you can integrate $x$ from $y^2$ to $2+y$. However the answers then say that you can also integrate $y$ from $-1$ to $2$. ( Why do they do this.

so you would get.

$$\int_{-1}^2\int_{y^2}^{y+2}\int_0^x  \,dzdxdy=36/5$$

But this $36/5$ is just a guess. So my two main questions are, where does the $-1$,and $2$ come from and how did I get $36/5$?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is that the first two conditions on K, $x\ge y^2$ and $x- y\le 2$ do not involve z so can be graphed in two dimensions. $x= y^2$ is the parabola with vertex (0, 0) opening to the right, x-axis as axis of symmetry.  $x- y= 2$ is the line through (0, 2) and (2, 0).  The region of integration is the region inside the parabola to the left of that line.  $x= y^2$ and $x- y= 2$ intersect where $x- y= y^2- y= 2$.  Completing the square, $y^2- y+ \frac{1}{4}= \frac{9}{4}$. $(y- 1/2)^2= 9/4$.  $y- 1/2= \pm 3/2$, y= -1 and 2.

So we can take y from -1 to 2 and, for each y, x goes from $y^2$ to $y+ 2$.

Then we have the third condition, $0\le z\le x$ so for each x, y, z goes from 0 to x.

The integral is
$\int_{y=-1}^2\int_{x= y^2}^{y+2}\int_{z= 0}^x dzdxdy= \int_{y=-1}^2\int_{x= y^2}^{y+2}x dxdy= \frac{1}{2}\int_{y=-1}^2 (y+2)^2-(y^2)^2 dy= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^2 (y^2+ 4y+ 4- y^4) dy= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{3}y^3+ 2y^2+ 4y- \frac{1}{5}y^5\right]_{-1}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the $x$-coordinates must obey $y^2 \leq x \leq y+2$.
This is only possible if $y^2 \leq y+2$, which is equivalent to $(y-2)(y+1)\leq 0$,
which in turn requires $y \leq 2$ and $y\geq -1$.

To get the volume, evaluate one integral after the other:
$$\int_0^x dz = x$$
$$\int_{y^2}^{y+2} x dx = \frac{1}{2}[(y+2)^2-y^4] = \frac{1}{2}(y^2+4y+4-y^4)$$
$$\int_{-1}^{2}\frac{1}{2}(y^2+4y+4-y^4)dy = \frac{1}{6}(2^3+1)+(4-1)+2\cdot3-\frac{1}{10}(2^5+1)=\frac{3}{2}+3+6-\frac{33}{10}=\frac{15+90-33}{10}=\frac{72}{10}=\frac{36}{5}$$